# Can argparse handle more than one positional command line arguements?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

In the examples I saw,argparse all handles just one positional commandline argument, and arbitrarily number of optional commandline arguments. So I wonder if it can handle more than one positional arguments? If yes, how does it do and how are the commandline arguments specified?  Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but have you tried `enumerate(sys.argv)` ?

Answer (score 2):

> So I wonder if it can handle more than one positional arguments? If yes, how does it do and how are the commandline arguments specified?

Well, the *very first* example in the [argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) handles multiple non-option arguments.  So that's probably a good place to start.

Here's a trivial example; place the following in `argtest.py`:

```
import argparse


def parse_args():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument('--option1', '-1')
    p.add_argument('--option2', '-2')
    p.add_argument('commandline1')
    p.add_argument('commandline2')
    return p.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = parse_args()
    print p
```

And then:

```
python argtest.py
usage: argtest.py [-h] [--option1 OPTION1] [--option2 OPTION2]
                  commandline1 commandline2
argtest.py: error: too few arguments
```

Or:

```
python argtest.py hello world
Namespace(commandline1='hello', commandline2='world', option1=None, option2=None)
```

Comment: Does the order between `p.add_argument('commandline1')` and `p.add_argument('commandline2')` matters?

Comment: What happens if you swap the position of those two lines and re-run the example?

Answer (score 1):

yes,

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="my_example")

# these are your positional arguments
parser.add_argument("first", type=int, nargs=1)                                          
parser.add_argument("second", type=str, nargs=1)

# this is your optional one
parser.add_argument("-r", this is an optional argument)

args = parser.parse_args()
parser.print_help()
print args.first args.second
```

On the command line

```
$ python argtest1.py 5 'c' -r R
```

Output:

```
usage: argtest1.py [-h] [-r R] first second                                     

my_example                                                                      

positional arguments:                                                           
  first                                                                         
  second                                                                        

optional arguments:                                                             
 -h, --help  show this help message and exit                                   
 -r R        this is an optional argument                                      

[5] ['c']
```

Note that you can put the positional arguments after the optional one on the command line:  `python argtest1.py -r R 5 'c'`. You could also do this:  `python argtest1.py 5 -r R 'c'`. Obviously you can't do this `python argtest1.py -r R 'c' 5`.